# Why does `ip route show` not produce any output in my script from systemd service

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, iproute

Service..

```
[Unit]
Description=testing
Requires=network-online.target
After=NetworkManager.service

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=testing
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

test.sh...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
nmcli connection up router.wired
echo ***
nmcli connection show
echo ***
ip route show
```

output..

```
testing[779]: Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/Network>
testing[772]: ***
testing[1468]: NAME          UUID  TYPE      DEVICE
testing[1468]: router.wired  xxxx  ethernet  enp1s0
testing[1468]: router        xxxx  wifi      --
testing[772]: ***
```

Why does `ip route show` not display any output despite the connection being up.  And how can I have the connection already up without having to call `nmcli connection up`.

If I take out `nmcli connection up` from my script the machine will boot into that connection anyway at which point I can manually call my service with `sudo service test start` and I get expected results from `ip route show` including a default gateway.

**Unsatisfactory solution...**

It seems the problem is the ordering of systems at boot up because I tried disabling my service at boot and instead tried activating it with a timer unit with `OnBootSec=50` and that worked.  I tried what seems like every possible dependency with `network.target`, `network-online.target`, and `NetworkManager.service` with no luck.

Comment: Use `systemd-networkd` instead of Network manager. Or IIRC in ststemd there were documentation how to check if network is really online (the normal "online" means just "attached"), and do rest after that. The problem: systemd just start networkManager, which may takes some time to configure, but systemd has so way to know it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `ip route` simply exits too fast for systemd-journald to correctly detect which unit it belongs to. Check the *global* `journalctl -b` to see if it has the output you wanted. (It's a known issue.)

In addition, though:

1. `Requires=` does not imply `After=`, so your service does not actually wait for network-online.target to be reached. You need to explicitly say `After=network-online.target`.

   (It does imply After= if the dependency comes *from* a target, but not in any other case.)
2. By default, network-online.target is actually empty – it's up to you to enable an appropriate "wait" service, such as `systemd-networkd-wait-online` or in your case `NetworkManager-wait-online`. Make sure you have the latter enabled, otherwise the target will do nothing.
3. *Your* service, on the other hand, should **not** be in `WantedBy=network-online.target`. That's not what the target is for.

Comment: A lot of good info and well explained, thanks.  I'll test out enabling `NetworkManager-wait-online` service and changing back to `After`.  All of this reminds me how terrible systemd is.  It shouldn't be so difficult to get triggers for "online" and a trigger for end of boot.